# select distinct words from pdf files stored in FILESTREAM

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, filestream

I have a SQL Server 2008 database that stores PDF files in FILESTREAM. I've enabled full-text search on those PDF files using Adobe iFilter. Full text search works properly.
Now, I want to be able to select all distinct words from that PDFs and display every word in a new row. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: You could look at [`sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721269%28SQL.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I think you've misinterpreted my question. For example: If I had a PDF document stored in filestream, and that document contains the following text: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", I want to be able to display every distinct word in a new row like: 

the
quick
brown
fox
jumps
over
lazy
dog

Comment: That TVF will allow you to "select all distinct words from the indexed documents and display every word in a new row" so if I have then your question must be very unclear.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Just tried sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document and it seems that it is what I want. Thank you.